# log multidimensional array of objects php

Tags: php, logging, serialization, json

I have to log below array of objects in a file and then read it.
my variable is $myObject.
var_dump($myObject) gives below array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(MyClassA)#179 (2) {
    ["_flag":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_myClassB":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(MyClassB)#187 (5) {
        ["_flag":protected]=>
        bool(false)
      }
    }
  }
```

MyClassA and MyClassB are two other classes.

How can I log it and retreive it. After retreiving I want to use the methods of MyClassA like MyClassA->getFlag after retreiving.

I am using below method to log it:

```
$fp = fopen("myfilepath", 'a');
fputcsv($fp, serialize( $myObject));
fclose($fp);
```

But it's logging in non-readable format.

Thanks

SOLUTION:

I thought serialization creates content in readable format. But I am worng. I am able to get the data when I unserialized it.
:)

Comment: I know that in Java, C#, ... you have something called "serialization" to store objects and retrieve them as such. I don't know about PHP but it might be a good starting point I guess?

Comment: I have tried serialization. But it's not able to serialize the objects inside objects. The stored log file is not readable.

Comment: Should it be saved in a readable format then? or just readable by code? EDIT: what about giving every class (if it works that way) a "serializable" argument?

Comment: why do you use 'fputcsv'? try fputs() or file_put_contents()

Comment: Let me try by unserializing it. I thought when we log it by serializing, the log files should have content in readable format.

Comment: @Tikkes
I am able to retrieve it. I thought serialization creates content in readable format. Many thanks  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stringToSaveInFile = serialize($array);
```

to reuse:

```
$array = unserialize($stringToSaveInFile)
```

the first function (serialize) convert your array/object in a string that you can save where you want... after that, when you'll read that string again, you'll can convert it into an object by the 'unserialize' function

**EDIT**:

look at this example (edited to save data in a file):

```
class A
{
    public function ciao() {
        echo "CIAO";
    }
}

class B
{
    public function hello() {
        echo "HELLO";
    }
}

$a = array(new A, new B);
$ser = serialize($a);
file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $ser);
$uns = file_get_contents('mydata.txt');
$uns[0]->ciao();
```

Comment: When I serialize it, MyClassA and MyClassB is not serialized and i got a non readable file. The method which I am using to log it, have updated in my question.

Comment: mhh maybe i don't understand your needs.. to get the code you posted i think you have user a var_dump($array) or something similar right? ok, to save it and then reuse it later you must serialize it and then unserialize it as i wrote.. if you don't want it sorry but i don't understand

Comment: check last edit.. note that to use MyClassA and MyClassB you MUST include the class files when you unserialize the data. You're saving objects, not the class definitions

Comment: I am able to retrieve it. I thought serialization creates content in readable format. Many thanks :)